# How to avoid the prompt in `revert-buffer`

Tags: interactive, revert-buffer

I'm trying to get rid of the annoying prompt at the end of `revert-buffer`. This prompt would make sense in a lesser text editor where reverting the buffer is an irreversible action (pardon the pun). However, most of the time when I want to revert buffer I actually want it to do that, and do it right away.

One solution I've come up with was to call the non-interactive counterpart of the `revert-buffer` function

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-r") (lambda () (revert-buffer nil t t))
```

but this for some reason ignores the second optional argument and still prompts me.

Comment: @Drew it does seem to be awfully close to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this (and in keeping with the MS Windows key for reverting I bind it to `<f5>`).  It's similar to what you're using, but not quite the same.  I've been using it for a  ***l o n g**   *t i m e** .

```lisp
(defun revert-buffer-no-confirm ()
  "Revert buffer without confirmation."
  (interactive) (revert-buffer t t))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set "revert-without-query" to t.

Comment: Nope. It needs to be set to a regex for files. Also setting it to the aforementioned regex doesn’t seem to work.